# max-width:100% and display:flex in IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, flexbox

In order to center an image inside a bootstrap row I use `display: flex`.

When ***zooming***, an image behaves fine in all browsers except for IE.

Please see screen shots for IE:

[image] and other browsers:

[image]

and the code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  align-self: center;
}
.col > div {
  align-self: center;
}
[class*='col-'] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col" id="col1">
      <div>
        <img id="img1" class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div>
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div>
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is what is the reason for such a behavior in IE? Is there a pure CSS solution for this issue? For now I have a JavaScript solution adjusting an image width on window resize.

Thanks